# Can I permanently give another player a weapon in Grand Theft Auto 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

We've got a crew with some higher level players and quite a few beginners. When we're doing co-op missions we want the beginners to have access to higher level weaponry as often they only have pistols or micro SMGs.

If I wanted to give another crew member my modified SMG how does that work? I know I can drop the weapon/ ammo but when they pick it up how long do they have it for?

Do they get the weapon permanently? Or does it disappear when they die/ at the end of the mission? And if it does disappear do I get it back?

I'm happy to give out weaponry to less fortunate crew members but I don't want to give away $100k in weapons if it's just going to mysteriously disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some anecdotal evidence in response to my question.

Short answer: No

Long answer:

We spent an evening playing co-op missions as a crew. A number of the higher level players would drop weapons for lower level players.

1. Dropping a weapon removes it from your weapon wheel and you need to repurchase it at Ammunation to get it back again.
2. The players who picked up the weapons seemed to lose them over time. It was hard to work out when the weapons would disappear from their inventories but it seemed to be when they were killed while the gifted weapon was active.

Point two is hard to work out with out a lot of complicated testing. It could of also been that they lost their weapon after a mission, or if they left the session, or if they hadn't unlocked that particular weapon yet.

Still a bit confusing sorry, but hopefully someone can come along and give a better/ clearer answer.